# Convert combobox string value to int in C# AND pass value in SQL server DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I hope I can explain clearly my dilemma with programming. I'm fairly new in programming so please bear with me. I am using C# and SQL Server 2014.

I made a database in SQL server with tables named Roles and AccountRegistration:

Roles Table has RoleId(pk) and RoleName while
AccountRegistration table has Username(pk), Password, RoleId(fk), FullName, Address.

Both tables are related through RoleID

Now, I created an Account Registration form (C#) with Username, Password, FullName, Address and RoleName.

RoleName is in a combobox, if user picks Admin or Employee how can this be converted into an int so it can be passed on to the RoleId field?

Here is what I have tried (using SQL server only), but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO AccountRegistration(RoleID)
SELECT a.RoleName
FROM Roles a
INNER JOIN AccountRegistration b ON cast(a.RoleId as nvarchar(255))=b.RoleID
```

Error msg:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Admin' to data type int.

I haven't tried coding this in C# since I'm still trying to figure out the logic.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=**;Password=****");
       

        public FrmAddNewAccount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmAddNewAccount_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Roles", con);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            cmbRole.DisplayMember = "RoleName";
            cmbRole.ValueMember = "RoleId";
            cmbRole.DataSource = dataSet;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into AccountRegistration(Username, Password, RoleID, FullName, Address) VALUES ('" + txtUsername.Text + "', '" + txtPassword.Text + "', '" + cmbRole.Text + "', '" + txtFullName.Text +"', '"+txtAddress.Text+"')", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

       
        private void cmbRole_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string RoleId = cmbRole.SelectedValue.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Just change this `INSERT INTO AccountRegistration(RoleID)
SELECT a.RoleName`, to this `INSERT INTO AccountRegistration(RoleID)
SELECT a.RoleId`

Answer (score 1):

you must bind RoleId and RoleName to a comboBox.

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection("Your Sql Server Connection");
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Roles",sqlConnection);
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            comboBoxRoles.DisplayMember = "RoleName";
            comboBoxRoles.ValueMember = "RoleId";
            comboBoxRoles.DataSource = dataSet;
```

when item has selected in ComboBox, you must send selectedValue as RoleId to t-sql For insert in table

```
 private void comboBoxRoles_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string RoldId = comboBoxRoles.SelectedValue.ToString();
        //RoleId = 35 for example
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @mohsen but I'm still getting an error, would you know where have I gone wrong? I think it's with the '"+cmbRole.Text+"'

Comment: I have edited my post with the codes. The error comes from the sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); Still getting the error that says can't convert nvarchar to int.

Comment: In INSERT query of AccountRegistration you should pass RoleId, which you get from comboBoxRoles.SelectedValue". Passing RoleName will not solve your problem. and also your INSERT query should be simple INSERT query for AccountRegistration table without doing any operation on Role table.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a SQL question.  THe reason it doesn't work is because 'Admin' isn't a number.  What you'll need to do in C# is something like this (I'll leave you to code the actual read from SQL Server):

```
string[] positionTypes = new String { "admin", "manager", "peon" }; //fill the array with your positions.
public static int ConvertFromPosition(string pos)
{
       return positionTypes.IndexOf(pos.ToLower().Trim());
}
```

That's just a quick and dirty with the information you supplied us. If you need specific numeric values that don't equate to these indeces, you will need an `enum`to house the values and a `switch` statement to run the comparison.

```
public enum MyEnum
        {
            Admin = 10,
            Manager = 20,
            Peon = 30
        }

public static int ConvertFromPosition(string pos)
{
       switch(pos.ToLower().Trim())
         {
           case "admin": return MyEnum.Admin; break;
           case "manager": return MyEnum.Manager; break;
           case "peon": return MyEnum.Peon; break;
           default:
                Throw new ApplicationException("Position " + pos + " is not a valid position.");
         }

}
```

Please note that there are much safer ways to compare strings, and that like I said, this is all just the quick and dirty.  It gets more complicated if we're culture-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert query should have

"cmbRole.SelectedValue.ToString()" instead of "cmbRole.Text".

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into AccountRegistration(
Username, Password, RoleID, FullName, Address) VALUES 
('" + txtUsername.Text + "', '" + txtPassword.Text + "', '" + 
cmbRole.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', '" + txtFullName.Text +"', 
'"+txtAddress.Text+"')", con);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: this helped me. Thanks!